# Tabs in a Fragment dont show up

Tags: java, android, xml, tabs, fragment

I have read many questions here about tabs in a fragment, and did everything described here: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/FragmentTabHost.html

i got no error and the app doesn't crash or something, but the fragment is just empty. The JobFragment class is a simple fragment with just one label, but it isn't displayed.
here is my java code:

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.TabLayout;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTabHost;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

public class AutoFragment extends Fragment{
    private FragmentTabHost mTabHost;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        mTabHost = new FragmentTabHost(getActivity());
        mTabHost.setup(getActivity(), getChildFragmentManager(), R.layout.fragment_auto);
mTabHost.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec("simple").setIndicator("Simple"),
            JobFragment.class, null);
    mTabHost.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec("contacts").setIndicator("Contacts"),
            JobFragment.class, null);
    mTabHost.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec("custom").setIndicator("Custom"),
            JobFragment.class, null);
    mTabHost.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec("throttle").setIndicator("Throttle"),
            JobFragment.class, null);

    return mTabHost;
}

@Override
public void onDestroyView() {
    super.onDestroyView();
    mTabHost = null;
}

}
```

and here is my layout xml

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >


    <TabWidget
        android:id="@android:id/tabs"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" >
    </FrameLayout>
</LinearLayout>

</android.support.v4.app.FragmentTabHost>
```

Comment: can you post the complete layout and the mainactivity ? 

I think you are missing a start tab for </android.support.v4.app.FragmentTabHost>. Also are you properly coding the MainActivity similar to one described here :
https://maxalley.wordpress.com/2013/05/18/android-creating-a-tab-layout-with-fragmenttabhost-and-fragments/

Answer (score 0):

Try changing this line to:

```
  mTabHost.setup(getActivity(), getSupportFragmentManager(), R.layout.fragment_auto);
```